# SonarQube - Is it possible to delete multiple project analyses?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

V9.9.3 - Enterprise Edition

I'm trying to delete multiple Project analyses by passing multiple keys in a single call to /api/project_analyses/delete, but it seems like only one analysis is getting deleted per call

The documentation seems a bit unclear, is there no way to delete multiple project analyses with a single SonarQube Web API call or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete multiple project analyzes at once, but you can make a little script to do your work:

like this:

```
import requests

sonar_url = "http://your-sonar-server/api/ce/"  # Replace with your server URL
auth = ("username", "your_api_token")  # Replace with your credentials

project_keys = ["project1", "project2", "project3"]  # List of projects to delete

for project_key in project_keys:
    endpoint = f"projects/{project_key}/analyses"
    response = requests.delete(sonar_url + endpoint, auth=auth)

    if response.status_code == 204:
        print(f"Analysis for {project_key} deleted successfully.")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to delete analysis for {project_key}: {response.text}")
```